# Concatenating ECHO syntax in PHP

Tags: php, syntax, echo

I have made a small function ([WordPress](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WordPress)), using `echo .`

```
/* .. Some code */
switch ($linktype) {
    case "next":
        echo '<p class="next">' . previous_post_link('%link',''.$prevthumbnail.'') . '</p>';
        break;
    case "prev":
        echo '<p class="prev">' . next_post_link('%link',''.$nextthumbnail.'') . '</p>';
        break;
}
/* .. Some other code*/
```

Using the "regular" concatenation syntax that I know...

```
echo '<p class="next">'. previous_post_link('%link',''.$prevthumbnail.'') . '</p>';
```

...produces...

```
<p class="next"></p>< result of previous_post_link() >
```

I obviously need `<p class="next">< result of previous_post_link() ></p>`. I have found some post suggesting to replace the dots **('.')** with commas **(',')**, so now I have...

```
echo '<p class="next">' , previous_post_link('%link',''.$prevthumbnail.'') , '</p>';
```

...which works. Is this a "correct" way to address the problem, or is this just a "hack" that works? Is there a better approach?

Answer (score 28):

**Commas are faster.**

The `echo` construct allows multiple "parameters".  When you `echo` with commas, the output is sent straight to the buffer piece by piece.  When you use `.`, it has to concatenate first.

This won't make a huge dent in speed for most applications, but I generally make it a habit to use commas for `echo` anyway.

Here's a benchmark, if you're curious:
http://www.electrictoolbox.com/php-echo-commas-vs-concatenation/

---

**EDIT:** Now, here's why things are "out of order".  (Apologies to all, as I just now figured out that this was the root question the whole time.)  When you `echo` with `.`, you concatenate first before `echo` gets to do its job.  To do that, each expression needs evaluated first.  Consider this:

```
echo (5+5) . (10+10);
```

PHP will first evaluate `(5+5)` and then `(10+10)`.  This is equivalent to turning it into this:

```
echo 10 . 20;
```

And then these need concatenated, so they are converted to strings and become this:

```
echo "1020";
```

Does that make sense?  Now consider the function `previous_post_link()`.  @Tim is quite right that there is no return value from this function.  When that function is evaluated, it returns nothing and echos something.  So if we do this:

```
echo "test" . previous_post_link();
```

First, both things are evaluated.  `"test"` is already a string, but we need to run the function `previous_post_link()` first to get its return value for concatenation.  When ran, `previous_post_link()` outputs something, and returns nothing.  `"test"` is then concatenated with nothing, and that concatenation is output via `echo`.

Now, suppose we use commas instead:

```
echo "test", previous_post_link();
```

PHP evaluates all of the "parameters" for the `echo` construct in order, and outputs them.  First, `"test"` is output, and then `previous_post_link()` is evaluated, which has its own output, and returns nothing, so nothing is output for it.

I hope this is clearer.  Post if not.

Comment: @Kyle you'd better remain ignorant in this. This "benchmark" makes no sense.

Comment: Not to mention that whole answer is complete offtopic.

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel, Care to explain how my answer is off topic? On almost any day you post stuff like this on SO I agree with you, but you've got me stumped this time.

Comment: thank you all, but my question was less concerned with speed and more with php learning . I wanted to understand when I should use commas and when to use dots. how can I predict this behaviour in the future ? How can I know what the echo result order will be ? because in my example, it just echoed the HTML part, and only AFTER the function.... at any rate, @brad : thanks for the info and the link..I assume now that it IS correct to do that , although I am still confused as the "why" and he future "how´s"

Comment: @Brad, thank you for following this. so If I understand correctly, when using echo - everything that needs to be EVALUATED in some way (expression, function) will be inevitably "pushed" to the end when using dots? because otherwise, I have a problem understanding why in my code, it opened AND closed the <p> tag (using the 1st and 3rd parts - or strings) and only then output the result from the function. It is quite not intuitive for use . But it IS very good to know that commas resolve this problem. (but then again - if this is the case , so WHY ever use the dots?)

Comment: @Brad - One more thing . now my question is what would happen in a more complicated example, like using strings, expressions, functions together . is there some known order of priority where I can know WHAT will be outputted first ? (I am of course asking that for better understanding and future reference - like i said, I am trying to learn better php). Is there some documentation on the priority order of execution inside commands / functions in PHP ?

Comment: @krembo99, apart frem learning PHP, one have to learn best practices. Here you are: it's better NOT TO MIX in one statement functions those returning values and those echoeing something on their own. Also it is better to make functions return some value, not echoing it. If some code looks "messy" for you - you can always create a function out of it and your code become neat. The more conistent code - the better: you are using concatenation all over your code - so, why not to use it in the echos too?

Answer (score 7):

The issue is that the [WordPress](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WordPress) `previous_post_link('%link',''.$prevthumbnail.'')` function actually has its own print command built-in, and it prints after the echo finishes its printing.

If you want to use this command within an echo (or to save to a string) you must use [`get_previous_posts_link`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_previous_posts_link), which instead of *printing* the value *returns* it.

Comment: thanks a bunch for answering. this is a bit aside from the main question about php syntax, but the problem for me using get_previous_posts_link() was that it does not accept parameters . I needed the $link parameter in previous_post_link() in order to output the post-thumb as the link...Now back to the main question - is this the reason why my output was in different order than my concatenation command (output first the xhtml, and only AFTER the function output ? and if so - like I asked in my other comment , is there a ways to predict this behavior ?

Comment: `Echo` is a built-in construct and not a real function, so it has some oddities about it.  I'd assume the reason is because when `echo` is called, it buffers the rest of the output until `echo` is done executing.  One way to work around this is to use two separate `echo` calls around `previous_post_link` - this will guarantee your output order.  I have done this on a WP site and despite not looking pretty, it *does* always work.

Comment: thanks, yes, I know this method of using multiple echos, but I just tried to learn a way to avoid it , mainly because what you stated yourself - it looks messy on the code ..

Comment: @krembo99 eventually you will learn that multiple echos are way better than one long line with tons of concetenations. several lines going in order are always better than one messy line. There is nothing to pursue for in one-liners.

Comment: @ Col. Shrapnel - yes, I know that - but in this phase those "experiment" are more educational than functional...see, today I already learned some stuff from that :-) thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

As a future memo to me:

```
$squarer = function ($x) { $out = $x*$x; echo "done!\n"; return $out; };

echo 'The square of 2 is ' . $squarer(2) . "!\n";
echo 'The square of 2 is ', $squarer(2), "!\n";

// **** OUTPUT ****
// done!
// The square of 2 is 4!
// The square of 2 is done!
// 4!
```

Answer (score 1):

> everything that needs to be EVALUATED in some way (expression, function) will be inevitably "pushed" to the end when using dots?

I can't reproduce this behavior. And, according to my knowledge, it should be contrary: echoed (not evaluated) values goes first, and then goes the result of the echo.

it seems you are mixing 2 matters - evaluation and echoing.
when concatenated, all expressions gets evaluated in turn:

```
function aplus($b){
  global $a;
  $a += $b;
}

$a=1;

echo $a."|".aplus(1).$a."||".aplus(1).$a;
```

while if you are of bad practice of mixing echo with statements having output of their own, this separate echo goes first:

```
function e($s){
  echo $s;
}

$a=1;

echo $a."|".e($a +1)."||".e($a+2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, an offtopic to counter Brad's offtopic.

He says that commas are faster.
That is just not true, as well as it's not true to say that one new car is cheaper than another if it costs 2 cents less. There are thousands differencies - service, gifts, even distance to the shop, etc. - making 2 cents difference totally negligible. A sane buyer wouldn't take 2 cents difference into account by any means.
Same here.

This answer is just deceiving, and makes you think wrong way. Wordpress is one of slowest applications in the world. **And if one really want to speed it up,** they have to do A LOT of job of profiling and speed optimization. An changing commas to dots wouldn't be in that number.
That's the point: one learns that commas are faster and thinks "I am writing fast code!!!" while it's utterly wrong. First, code itself is always fast. I't s *data manipulation* that makes your code slow! Say, Wordpresss is parsing and loading several-magabyte of localization data into memory every time it's called! Placing this data into some cache will make your wordpress 2 times faster! That's what I'd *"make a habit"* of.
While even if you change ALL dots in your code to commas, you will never ever be able to measure any difference. A real difference, not an artificial one. That's especially applicable to `echo` as no sane application would use echo for million times.

Comment: I agree with the point that there is no noticeable difference, but I see no harm in using commas anyway.  Suppose someone has some script setup outputting 10s of megs of data in variables... I certainly wouldn't want to needlessly concatenate that.  I'm also curious why you think your post is off-topic as well.

Comment: That's the point and you - alas! - still can't get it. If someone has some script setup outputting 10s of megs of data in variables - their problem is WAY bigger than these silly dots, and cannot be solved with commas.

Comment: if there is no noticeable difference - so, just don't mention it. Isn't it? What's the point in writing "it's faster" in bold letter if it's really isn't?

Comment: Sharpnel, He wanted to know the difference, and why anyone would ever suggestion replacing `.` with `,`.  I simply answered his question.  I put the first line in bold for readability, for those that didn't care to read why.  There is no reason not to use commas.  I also am not suggesting going through and removing all of your periods.  I agree, that'd be ridiculous, and last on the list of things to optimize.  But, there is no harm in using commas when you write the code in the first place.

Comment: You still cannot make your mind - if it's "faster" or not. If "faster" - you just didn't get the idea (and have no experience in measuring real world applications). If not - there is no point in your answer at all.

Comment: I am clearly unable to communicate what I am trying to say. Last attempt: In real world applications, the speed difference is too small to matter. The point to my answer is to answer krembo99's question about the difference between `,` and `.` when used with `echo`. Perhaps I should have been more clear about how negligible any speed increase might have been, but I thought the benchmark I linked to made that very obvious. You are welcome to continue to disagree, and I am happy you made your own post to clarify. I don't really care to discuss this further, as I seem to have trouble explaining.